# Проверка односвязного списка на уникальность элементов

Tags: c++, односвязный-список

Есть односвязный список, в который пользователь вводит элементы с клавиатуры. После формирования списка запускается функция, которая должна проверить, что бы элементы не повторялись. 
Я сравниваю первый элемент со всеми, потом второй со всеми и так далее. Но получается что когда элемент сравнивается сам с собой, то обнаруживаются повторения. Как избежать этого?

```
bool Check(Link* linkMain, int count) {
    Link* first;
    Link* temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            if (linkMain->data == temp->data) {
                cout << "Элементы повторяются!" << endl;
                return true;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        linkMain = linkMain->next;
        temp = first;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте внутренний цикл сделать так: " for (int j = i+1; j < count; j++) {}  "  :)

Comment: Сравнивайте каждый элемент не со всеми, а только с теми, которые идут после него (как Вам, собственно, и подсказал @АлександрМуксимов)

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему таким образом:

```
bool Check(Link* linkMain, int count) {
    int g = 0;
    Link* first = linkMain;
    Link* temp = linkMain;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            if (linkMain->data == temp->data) {
                g++;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        if (g == 2) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            g = 0;
        }
        linkMain = linkMain->next;
        temp = first;
    }
    return false;
}
```